# appwidget not updating itself

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I am working on android appwidget , There are issues updating appwidget periodically . Changed updating period to more than 30 minutes . Still not updating the widget

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

final static String ITEM_CLICK_ACTION = "ItemClick";
public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "TOAST_ACTION";

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,

int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Log.e("called", "omupdate");

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_lay);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,
                "Floating Text will be displayed here .. Daily Thoughts");

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RemoteServiceEmin.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        // intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.gridview, intent);

        // inflating list remote view

        Intent intentlist = new Intent(context, ListInflater.class);
        intentlist.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
        // intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listview, intentlist);

        // setting onclick on gridview
        Intent itemClickIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        itemClickIntent.setAction(ITEM_CLICK_ACTION);
        itemClickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        PendingIntent itemClickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, itemClickIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.gridview,
                itemClickPendingIntent);

        Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        toastIntent.setAction(MyWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.ll, toastPendingIntent);

        // appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], v);
        // appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (intent.getAction().equals(ITEM_CLICK_ACTION)) {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("text", intent.getExtras().getString("text"));
        Intent actIntent = new Intent();
        actIntent.setClass(context, ConfigurationActivity.class);
        actIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        actIntent.putExtras(extras);
        context.startActivity(actIntent);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "dfjdsfl", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}
```

}

this is My appwidget class, i can't track why isnt it updating after
`android:updatePeriodMillis="50000"`

thanks in advance ..

Comment: please show Your AppwidgetProvider.xml

Comment: sure but i think minimum time  for update is 30 minutes and here i am doing it in 50 seconds

Comment: <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_lay"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/logo"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="30000" >

</appwidget-provider>

Comment: if so then you can use Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the minimum actual time for widget update is 30 minutes  to avoid poor programmed widgets to dry battery. For frequent update of widget use AlarmManager to overcome this .

```
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds){

     long interval = 50000;
    Intent in = new Intent(context, Widgetclass.class);
in.setAction("Widgetupdate");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, in, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),interval, pi);
//add remaining code here
}
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals("widgetupdate")) {
watchWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            Widgetclass.class);
 RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_lay);
(AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)).updateAppWidget(
                    watchWidget, views);
}
declare this  receiver action in menifest file
```

Comment: and where should i do this stuff

Comment: Thanks @user123  but there is one more issue see next answer . please let me know if you have solution for that too